# XamlParseException after upgrading a Windows Phone 7.0 to Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have just upgraded an old project from WP7.0 to WP7.1 (MANGO), and now, after starting the app, I get this error in the main App.cs class, on the InitializeComponent method:

**The property 'IsOptimized' was not found in type 'DoubleAnimation'. [Line: 14 Position: 37]**

I have no idea how to fix this, since the "App" InitializeComponent method seems to be autogenerated

In line 14 I just have a reference to a resource dictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="keyname">
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/AppStyles.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

**Stack trace is not very helpful at all:**

```
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at WP7App.App.InitializeComponent()
   at WP7App.App..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass30.<GetCreateObjectDelegate>b__2a()
   at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.CreateKnownObject(IntPtr nativeRootPeer, UInt32 customTypeId, String initializationString, IntPtr& nativePeer, UInt32 isCreatedByParser)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.CreateUnknownObject(String assemblyName, String typeName, IntPtr nativeRootPeer, String initializationString, UInt32& customTypeId, UInt32& coreTypeId, UInt32& typeFlags, IntPtr& nativePeer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the resourcedictionary was referencing a style xaml file, with the "isoptimized" key:

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
```

removing the key fixed the problem